# Thingsboard API get all devices and time of latest activity

Tags: thingsboard

Using the python `tb_rest_client.rest_client_ce` API, I'm fetching all customer devices like this:

```
installations = {
    "installations": [
    ]
}
has_next = True
page = 0
while has_next:
    devices = self.client.get_customer_device_infos(customer_id=self.cid, page_size=64, page=page)

    for device in devices.data:
        installations["installations"].append({
            "id": device.name
        })

    has_next = devices.has_next
    page += 1
```

What I also want is the timestamp for the latest telemetry activity for each device. Is there a way to get this without sending an API request for each device?